# Gmail Api send from alias

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

I created a script that connects with the Gmail API using OAuth 2.0. It works perfectly, and I am able to send email from the authenticated account.

However, I can't send email from any of the account's aliases. If I try to do so I  get the following error message:

```
    "error": {
    "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden",
                "message": "[ACCOUNT] does not have privileges to [ALIAS] mailbox."
            }
        ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "[ACOUNT] does not have privileges to [ALIAS] mailbox."
    }
}
```

I have verified that the alias is setup in Gmail and Google Apps.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

Don't try to make the call as the alias (e.g. alias shouldn't be in the URL as the user ID), just put the alias email address in the "From" header in your sent message.

so in python would be something like:

> email = "To: someone@example.com\r\nFrom: myalias@gmail.com\r\nSubject: blah\r\n\r\nbody goes here"
>
> gmail.users().messages().send(userId="me", body={'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(email)})

Comment: Even if you have your secondary domain configured and the email exists as an alias, you also have to go into your Gmail settings and add the alias as a "send as" address. After that, setting it as the "From" address like this works

Answer (score 0):

i found same error..

when i add user i use for sendmail on https://www.google.com/webmasters on domain i used, and on https://admin.google.com for API access

and now it's work..

hope this help..