# google apps script gmail app sending as alias

Tags: email, google-apps-script, smtp, gmail

I am trying to use apps script to send myself an email from a google sheet linked to a google form.

I have a gmail account with `email@yahoo.com` as an alias. I can send fine using my alias directly from gmail, but when I try to do it via apps script it gives me this error:

> Reporting-MTA: dns; googlemail.com Arrival-Date: Tue, 06 Aug 2019
>   09:46:58 -0700 (PDT) X-Original-Message-ID:
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; email@yahoo.com Action: failed
>   Status: 5.0.0 Remote-MTA: dns; smtp.mail.yahoo.com (98.136.96.80, the
>   relay for the domain.) Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 Request failed;
>   Mailbox unavailable Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 06 Aug 2019 09:46:59 -0700
>   (PDT)

Here's my script.

```
  var email = e.values[1];
  var name = e.values[2];
  var msg = e.values[3];

GmailApp.sendEmail('email@yahoo.com', 'Contact', name + ': ' + msg, {from: 'email@yahoo.com', replyTo: email});
```

I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: Try sending it to a gmail recipient from your yahoo alias

Comment: I've never tried this, I wonder if you have to add it too "Send Mail As" in your Gmail account settings.  The description for the from in Google Apps Doc is `the address that the email should be sent from, which must be one of the values returned by getAliases()`  [Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases())

Comment: It's already added as a 'Send Mail As' in gmail which is why I can send from the alias directly from gmail ... I just can't do it via the script ... which I think is written properly ...?

Comment: Why would changing the recipient matter? @TheMaster

Comment: I just did it to another email of mine and it worked fine.  I did check the getAliases() to insure that email was in the list.

Comment: Search the diagnostic error code: `smtp; 550 Request failed;`

Comment: I think your final server rejected the email because of a spam filter.

Comment: @testing123 Your code is correct and works fine for me. May I ask you two things: 1. How did you set up your external (yahoo) account as an alias in Gmail? 2. When you log `GmailApp.getAliases()` - is your yahoo account showing up in the list of alias?

Comment: @ziganotschka log `GmailApp.getAliases()` shows the yahoo email in position 1. I have the yahoo address as a Send Mail As address in gmail with alias checked using smtp.mail.yahoo.com with port 465. I also gmailified the yahoo address in 'Check mail from other accounts:' Wonder if that has anything to do with it ...

Comment: @testing123 Instead of GmailApp try to use Gmail API for Apps Script as described here https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/apps-script, setup the alias with Users.settings.sendAs.create() and set up smtpMsa https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs. According to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings it seems to be required for external addresses. When you finish the set-up, send an email with the alias assigned to the "from" header like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25491283/11599789